# Help with another mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I Would like to select the count of the newly added DISTINCT product_id in the table

```
ID    product_id
 1      abc
 2      abc
 3      cat
 4      dog
 5      dog
 6      man
 7      man
 8      bat
 9      bat
10      abc
11      cat
12      dog
13      dog
```

I want a query that gives me a similar result from the above table - 
dog -2
cat -1
abc -1
bat -2
man -2

*Thanks in advance
***EDIT**
I have a table to store images of products, I keep adding new images of products in this table and I want to select the count of the newly added images of that particular product(ignoring the previous sets of images added earlier in the table) ... I hope I have made myself clear

***EDIT I found the answer to my question..**

```
SELECT COUNT(xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id) FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
WHERE xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id >(SELECT  MAX(xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id) 
                             FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
                             WHERE xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id= (SELECT  DISTINCT xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id 
                                                             FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
                                                             ORDER BY xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id DESC LIMIT 5,1)) 
   GROUP BY xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id
```

Comment: your question is unclear, how do you define "newly added"?

Comment: Do you mean to go from newest to oldest, and upon first seeing a new string see how many times it is followed by the very same string?

Comment: You've spent enough time on this site to at least attempt at asking questions with full details.

Comment: Yes!Zed, that is exactly what I want.... go from newest to oldest, and upon first seeing a new string see how many times it is followed by the very same string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id) FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
WHERE xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id >(SELECT  MAX(xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id) 
                             FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
                             WHERE xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id= (SELECT  DISTINCT xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id 
                                                             FROM xbrygame_scrnsmkv 
                                                             ORDER BY xbrygame_scrnsmkv.id DESC LIMIT 5,1)) 
   GROUP BY xbrygame_scrnsmkv.product_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You could redesign your table to also have a counter:

```
ID    product_id  consecutive
 8      bat         1
 9      bat         2
10      abc         1
11      cat         1
12      dog         1
13      dog         2
```

When inserting to the table, first check the last entry and its consecutive counter. If you are inserting the same element, increase the counter, otherwise insert 1. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (product_id, consecutive) VALUES
('newProd', CASE (SELECT product_id FROM Table WHERE ID = MAX(ID))
              WHEN 'newProd' THEN
                           (SELECT consecutive FROM Table WHERE ID = MAX(ID)) + 1
              ELSE 1
            END);
```

Then you can make your selection as:

```
SELECT product_id, consecutive
FROM Table
WHERE ID IN
  (SELECT MAX(ID)
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY product_id)
```

---

Original answer was:

```
SELECT Filename, COUNT(Filename) as Count
FROM Table
GROUP BY Filename
```

Comment: I did concider that too but if you look at his data, he only counts the "higher" ids.

Comment: I have edited the post to make myself more clear...Please see the example table and the result set

Answer (score 1):

If you only want 'newly added' records, you will have to indicate somehow what a newly added record is. Your dbms may support dating by default on all records (I have an inkling that Ingres may do this, but I may be imagining it - it's been a while since I've used it), but you will probably need to add something to the row yourself.

You could add a datetime field to filter on, then you can do as Zed has done:

```
SELECT Filename, COUNT(Filename) as Count
FROM Table
WHERE DateAdded > (FilterDate)
GROUP BY Filename
```

(**EDIT** where FilterDate is the DateTime after which you deem a record to be new, for example you could set this to Now minus 60 minutes - the syntax will change depending on DBMS)

or you could add a 'new' flag bit column and set it to true for each new record, them turn it off after it is read or some arbitary interval.

Comment: I have a date_added field in the table ...What is filterDate?